# How to relocate the git-repo urls?

Tags: git, repo, qualcomm, git-repo

I'm trying to build driver for qca8081 phy and notice that it is pointing to old CAF URLs. That is causing problem when I tried to perform `repo sync`

per their driver build guide following is CLI, but it doesn't work.

```
repo init -u git://codeaurora.org/quic/qsdk/releases/manifest/qstak -b release -m caf_AU_LINUX_QSDK_NHSS.QSDK.8.0.1_TARGET_ALL.7.0.1681.673.032.xml --repo-url=git://codeaurora.org/tools/repo.git --repo-branch=caf-stable
```

I could change this to following to pass that step,

```
repo init -u https://git.codelinaro.org/clo/qsdk/releases/manifest/qstak.git -b caf_migration/release -m caf_AU_LINUX_QSDK_NHSS.QSDK.8.0.1_TARGET_ALL.7.0.1681.673.032.xml
```

However, the following 2nd step fails with ***error***.

```
$ repo sync -j1 --no-tags -c
fatal: unable to access 'https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/qsdk/oss/tools/meta/': Received HTTP code 502 from proxy after CONNECT
```

**EDIT-1:** per reply from @phd, I tried changing the git config via following two commands, as well as editing `config` file in all internal repositories. They both end-up asking me Username/password

```
git config --global url.https://.insteadOf git://
git config --global url.https://git.codelinaro.org/clo/.insteadOf git://codeaurora.org/quic/
```

`Username for 'https://git.codelinaro.org':`

**P.S.** I'm behind corporate proxy if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`git config --global url.<base>.insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) to substitute URLs on the fly:

```
git config --global url.https://git.codelinaro.org/clo/.insteadOf git://codeaurora.org/quic/
```

Now try `repo sync` again.

Comment: thanks phd. that also doesn't work. I also tried replacing git with https `git config --global url.https://.insteadOf git://` but that also ended-up with same error

Comment: @user19410404 source.codeaurora.org should be fixed separately: `git config --global url.https://git.codelinaro.org/clo/.insteadOf https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/` The same for any additional URLs.

Comment: this is exactly what I tried. Now I've two entries in my `~/.gitconfig`. 1. for codelinaro and 2. https. I **also** tried editing config file of each repo inside `.repo` directory and both ways it ends up with same error: `Username for 'https://git.codelinaro.org':`

Comment: `git clone https://git.codelinaro.org/clo/qsdk/releases/manifest/qstak.git -b caf_migration/release` works for me, doesn't ask for password. Could the request for username/password come from your corporate proxy? BTW the commands to rewrite URLs should be `git config --global url.https://git.codelinaro.org/clo/.insteadOf git://codeaurora.org/quic/ && git config --global --add url.https://git.codelinaro.org/clo/.insteadOf https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/` (note `--add`).

Comment: I could pass the 1st step `repo init` by changing the url to `git.codelinaro...` The problem is with 2nd step `repo sync` where it requires username/password for `git.codelinaro.org` so it doesn't look asking for proxy username/password.

Comment: I installed `repo` (I never used it) and ran `repo init && repo sync`. It asked me "Username:" and then reported a lot of errors most of which is "*fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/NHSS.QSDK.8.0.1*". It seems not all tags were moved to the new repository. Try a different tag.

Comment: thanks @phd for trying that. It looks there are some repository which requires pre-registration. for that it is asking for username/password. unfortunately i don't have that so kind of stuck here.

Answer (score 2):

`repo` wraps `git`, so `repo sync` will rely on whatever remotes are configured within Git for each repository.

For each affected repository,

1. `cd` to the repository directory
2. `git remote -v` to list current remotes; the first column is the remote name, and the second is the URL
3. `git remote set-url $REMOTE_NAME $NEW_URL`

Comment: oh, there are many. i'll try and change for each of them to see how it go. I was wondering there is some easy way like subversion where we can relocate the repostiry.

Comment: I modified all repos manually but now running `repo sync` is asking for `Username for 'https://git.codelinaro.org':` and the codelinaro account seems is only available to prior authorized users ONLY. I'm stuck wondering how to proceed.